# Unwanted timezone conversion for an incoming timestamp in spring boot app

Tags: java, timestamp, timezone, java-time, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to format the incoming timestamp in my spring boot app, but the code that I wrote is changing the timezone of the incoming timestamp. It is adding 5:30 hrs on its own which I don't want.

Here is my snippet:

```
String startTime = searchParams.getDeploymentStartDate();
System.out.println("startTime from req body in utc:"+startTime);
DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd' HH:mm:ss"
             , Locale.ENGLISH).ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
Date startDate = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(startTime, targetFormatter).toInstant());
System.out.println("startDate converted to desired format in IST:"+startDate);
```

Actual output:

```
startTime from req body in utc:2023-03-22T11:27:04Z
startDate converted to desired format in IST:Wed Mar 22 16:57:04 IST 2023
```

Desired output:

```
startTime from req body in utc:2023-03-22T11:27:04Z
startDate converted to desired format in IST:Wed Mar 22 11:27:04 IST 2023
```

Please help me find a way to convert the format without converting timezone.

Comment: It doesn't add 5:30. It just displays the date and time in the timezone of your machine, which happens to be IST which is 5:30 ahead of UTC. Tip 1: Stop using `java.util.Date`. When you print a `java.util.Date` directly, it will always print its content in the timezone of your machine, which is why you see it in IST. Tip 2: To print your timestamp in a specific timezone, format it using a formatter with the desired timezone configured (on the formatter).

Comment: I agree with Jasper. The time is converted and shown in your local timezone which is IST and that's what you are trying to print right? The equivalent of UTC time in IST.

Comment: Please confirm that you want to preserve the wall-clock time (here 11:27:04) thereby giving you a point in time that is 5 hours 30 minutes earlier than the incoming time from the request? Asking because I have a hard time making sense if such a requirement.

Comment: If you insist: (1) Parse using `OffsetDateTime reqDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-03-22T11:27:04Z");`. (2) Check that `reqDateTime.getOffset().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)` (because from what you told us we have no idea what to do if not). (3) Convert to your computer’s time zone keeping the wall clock time: `ZonedDateTime sameWallClockTime = reqDateTime.atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());`. Gives `2023-03-22T11:27:04+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]`. (4) Optionally: If you need a `Date` for a legacy API: `Date.from(sameWallClockTime.toInstant());`. Gives `Wed Mar 22 11:27:04 IST 2023`.

Answer (score 1):

## tldr

```
java.util.Date juDate = 
    Date                                   // Legacy class. Best to avoid wherever possible. Represents a moment as seen in UTC (zero offset) but it’s poorly designed `toString` applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text. 
    .from(                                 // A new method on old legacy class to bridge between legacy and modern classes. 
        java.time.Instant                  // The modern class for representing a moment as seen with an offset of zero. 
        .parse( "2023-03-22T11:27:04Z" )   // Parsing text in standard ISO 8601 format. 
    )
;
```

Best to avoid the terribly flawed legacy date-time class `java.util.Date`. Use only *java.time* classes.

```
Instant
.parse( "2023-03-22T11:27:04Z" )  // Returns an `Instant` object. 
.atZone(                          // Adjust from UTC to a specific time zone. 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )   // Returns a `ZoneId` object. 
)                                 // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## Incorrect formatting pattern, also unnecessary

> 2023-03-22T11:27:04Z

> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd' HH:mm:ss"
> , Locale.ENGLISH).ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

Your formatting pattern for parsing does not match the input data. The `Z` on the end of the input indicates the date and time represent a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Your formatter ignores that crucial part.

And, the formatting pattern needs other fixes: a stray single-quote mark, and a SPACE that should instead be `T`.

Furthermore, there is no need to define this formatting pattern at all. Your input text happens to comply with the ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2023-03-22T11:27:04Z" ) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time types

> Date startDate = …

Both `Date` classes bundled with Java are terribly flawed, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling. Avoid these classes. Use only the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

If you must have an object of the legacy classes to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date juDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Beware: The `toString` method of `java.util.Date` unfortunately applies the JVM’s current time zone while generating its resulting text. This design flaw may be adding to your confusion. A `java.util.Date` actually represents a moment with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

## Adjusting to a time zone

An `Instant` represents a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

If you want to view that moment through the lens of a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `java.util.Date` as it's poorly designed and may be deprecated in future.

Instead use `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

**Update:**

You have to use `ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId zone)` if you want to keep the same time with the change in timezone only.

From [ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId zone) JDK 8 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal-java.time.ZoneId-) :

> Returns a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone, retaining
> the local date-time if possible. This method changes the time-zone and
> retains the local date-time.

So, update the code (without using `java.util.Date`) to this:

```
String startTime = searchParams.getDeploymentStartDate();
System.out.println("startTime from req body in utc:" + startTime);
ZonedDateTime ist = ZonedDateTime.parse(startTime)
                .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println("startDate converted to desired format in IST:" 
             + ist.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z u")));
```

Output:

```
startTime from req body in utc:2023-03-22T11:27:04Z
startDate converted to desired format in IST:Wed Mar 22 11:27:04 IST 2023
```

**Note:** If you want the timestamp in a different timezone, then just pass that timezone in `ZoneId.of(...)`

I'm providing a list of ZoneIds from the [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) that are supported :

```
EST - -05:00
HST - -10:00
MST - -07:00
ACT - Australia/Darwin
AET - Australia/Sydney
AGT - America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
ART - Africa/Cairo
AST - America/Anchorage
BET - America/Sao_Paulo
BST - Asia/Dhaka
CAT - Africa/Harare
CNT - America/St_Johns
CST - America/Chicago
CTT - Asia/Shanghai
EAT - Africa/Addis_Ababa
ECT - Europe/Paris
IET - America/Indiana/Indianapolis
IST - Asia/Kolkata
JST - Asia/Tokyo
MIT - Pacific/Apia
NET - Asia/Yerevan
NST - Pacific/Auckland
PLT - Asia/Karachi
PNT - America/Phoenix
PRT - America/Puerto_Rico
PST - America/Los_Angeles
SST - Pacific/Guadalcanal
VST - Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
```

Comment: @BasilBourque Right. Updated.

Comment: @AnishB. your answer seems to be convincing to me, just one question though. I dont want to convert the timestamp to any timezone rather i just want to format it to this farmat: Wed Mar 22 11:27:04 IST 2023

Comment: @DivyaSingh Let me update my answer.

Comment: @DivyaSingh I have updated the code. Now it will work according to what you want.